# Keyboard matrix and its microcontroller type

Tags: microcontroller, keyboard

I'm planning to make a custom 108 keys keyboard from scratch. Unfortunately, I'm currently stuck in a circuitry situation. Is there a lean matrix that I can go with for this and what kind of microcontroller should I use?

I know this sounds very stupid (mainly because I am entirely new to this field), but is there a maximum amount of key switches for each pin on a microcontroller? If so, how do you tell? Is there a calculation for this?

Comment: It depends on how you wish to connect the switches. Every multiplexing method has it's pros and cons, see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing#Input_data_multiplexing and the chapter about problems

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you mean? typing or musical one?

Comment: @FMashiro thank you for the info!

Comment: @R.Joshi referring to a typing one yeah